# Calculate Probability using venn diagram

Tags: probability

Suppose a survey of 70 people produced the following results:
19 ate eggs for breakfast; 18 ate meat; 50 ate toast; 12 ate eggs and meat; 10 ate meat and toast; 13 ate eggs and toast; and nine ate all three. 
Illustrate using Venn diagram theory:
a)  How many ate none of the three?
b)  How many ate toast, but neither eggs nor meat?
c)  How may ate eggs and meat but not toast?
d)  What is the probability that a person ate meat only?
e)  What is the probability that a person ate none of the three?

Comment: What trouble are you having with this homework question?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to solve this is to draw the (triple) Venn diagram. Let $E =$ # of people who eat eggs, $M =$ # of people who eat meat, $T =$ # of people who eat toast. Then fill in your given information starting with $E\cap M\cap\ T$ (# of people who eat all three). The seven blanks to be filled in are:

$E\cap M \cap T = 9$ (given)

$(E\cap M) \text{ \\ } T = E \cap M - E\cap M \cap T = 12 - 9 = 3$

$(M\cap T) \text{ \\ } E = M \cap T - E\cap M \cap T = 10 - 9 = 1$

$(E\cap T) \text{ \\ } M = E \cap T - E\cap M \cap T = 13 - 9 = 4$

$E \text{ \\ } (M \cup T) = ... = 19 - (3 + 9 + 4) = 3$

$M \text{ \\ } (E \cup T) = ... = 18 - (3 + 9 + 1) = 5$

$T \text{ \\ } (E \cup M) = ... = 50 - (4 + 9 + 1) = 36$

a) The number that ate none of the three = $70 -$ (sum of above seven values) $= 70  - 61 = 9$.

b) The number that ate toast but neither eggs or meat $= 36$.

c) The number that ate eggs and meat but not toast $= 3$.

d) Probability that a person only only ate meat $= 5/70 = 1/14$.

e) Probability that a person ate none of the three $= 9/70$.